# How to pause a thread from altering data and resume back in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm studying on a traffic simulation project right now. However i have problem with pausing the simulation.Each car is considered as a thread in my app. When the simulation is running( *Cars* on the grid moving ) i want to pause it.

`Thread.suspend()` method doesnt work, since i have to stop the thread from altering data.

Let's say if there is a *car* on the road, and I click on pause button, the *car* should stay there and when i click start button it should be able to resume. I can't make the threads sleeping directly since it will block `UI`.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _I can't make the threads sleeping directly since it will block UI_ You are using separate worker threads for the cars. Why does suspending a worker thread block the UI that runs on the main thread?

Comment: Actually, it is quite weird, when i use myThread.suspend(); it doesnt lock ui; however, when i want to make it sleep for a specified time with thread.sleep() method, the ui gets locked.

Comment: thread.sleep() makes the current thread sleep for a specified time. If you are calling that in response to clicking your button then the UI thread will not response as it is sleeping for that duration.

Answer (score 2):

You don't suspend the thread. If you think each car should be in its own thread, give each car a 'Pause' method that will stop it from moving (but keep responding to other things).

I don't think you want a thread-per-car, though. Why not have multiple Car objects all moving in response to a timer?

Comment: I have so many thread-per-cars, and then i have a crossing class which contains a specific number of cars. But the crossing are threads as well, since we will have many crossings at the same time running. 

And the reason of thread-per-car is to make it possible for each car to take a turn. Since some of them will go different directions we can not have them as a group. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But i'll try to give each car a 'pause' method, and let you know about the result.

Comment: I did as you said, and now it pauses successfully, I was trying to pause all the cars together, not one by one :)

Thanks a lot.